# Alternative for point.x for google map api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a portion of code I'm working on: (this legacy code is drawing Circle using Polygon paths:

```
    GEvent.addListener(bigmap_rad, 'click', function(overlay, cpoint) {

        var radius = document.getElementById('circle_radius').value;             
         var c_center = new GLatLng(cpoint.y,cpoint.x);
        var c_marker = new GMarker(c_center);
        var latOffset = 0.01;
        var lonOffset = 0.01;
        var latConv = c_center.distanceFrom(new GLatLng(c_center.lat()+0.1, c_center.lng()))/100;
       var lngConv = c_center.distanceFrom(new GLatLng(c_center.lat(), c_center.lng()+0.1))/100; 
        // nodes = number of points to create polygon
        var nodes = 40;
        // Create an array of points
       var cpoints = [];
       var pointbegain     = null;
        // set the amount of steps from node
       var step = parseInt(360/nodes);
        // the for loop creates a series of points that define the circle, counting by the amount of steps, by 9 in the case of 40 nodes
       for(var i=0; i<=360; i+=step){
        var point1 = new GLatLng(c_center.lat() + (radius / latConv * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180)), 
        c_center.lng() + (radius / lngConv * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)));
         if(i==0){
           pointbegain= point1;
        }    

        cpoints.push(point1);
    }
    //cpoints.push(pointbegain);
    polygon = new GPolygon(cpoints, "#000000", 1, 1, "#8000000", 0.5);
    //bigmap_rad.addOverlay(polygon);
```

(Here bigmap_rad is a google map v2 Map object and cpoint is passed to that event listener)

I am using this google map v2 code to turn it into v3 . But stumbled on this

```
var c_center = new GLatLng(cpoint.y,cpoint.x);
```

I cant find the alternative of this cpoint.y and cpoint.x for google map api v3. Please someone suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `cpoint` come from?  What type of object is `bigmap_rad`?  I think we'll need to see more of your code, especially the V3 version of it

Comment: bigmap_rad is  a google map v2 Map object and cpoint is passed to that event listener . and I'm now searching the alternative of this cpoint for google map v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a solution. Just used this

```
var c_center = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng());
```

in place of

```
var c_center = new GLatLng(cpoint.y,cpoint.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by replacing the x and y with lat() and lng().

That would make your code be.

var c_center = new google.maps.LatLng(cpoint.lat(),cpoint.lng());

Maybe that could have worked and is a quick workaround that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

ok so you need to have an event listener on the map for clicks.  And you want to find out the point that's been clicked.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {       
  console.log(event.latLng);

  var yourCoordinates = event.latLng;
});
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments

Comment: No , I have edited that code so that you can have a look at that full code. I am trying to create a circle using polygon paths. Thanks a lot for your concern.